# How to change permission VM shared folder to 777 (drwxrwxrwx)?

Tags: linux

I'm using Oracle Linux 5.7 x86 on Virtual Box 5.1.8 Window 10 x64. I have shared a host folder Temp with VM and can access it and trying to copy its contents to VM but stuck at;

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /downloads
[root@localhost downloads]# cp /media/sf_Temp/*.zip
cp: target `/media/sf_Temp/V25347-01.zip' is not a directory
[root@localhost downloads]#
```

I guess I'll need to change the permissions of shared folder to 777 (drwxrwxrwx) but cannot. Is chmod 777 /media/sf_Temp right command for this?

```
[root@localhost sf_Temp]# ls -ld /media/sf_Temp
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 12288 Oct 25 20:46 /media/sf_Temp
[root@localhost sf_Temp]# ls -ld /downloads
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 19:14 /downloads
[root@localhost sf_Temp]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already root, you don't need any other permissions.

cp command needs two arguments, one for target file/folder, one for destination.

```
cp origfile newfile
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm

Comment: but notice that I'm using cp in destination directory and still not able to copy, plz suggest full cp code